# I'm trying to install node-gyp node packages through npm, but it not working

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting following error when running `npm install -g node-gyp` command on Ubuntu and Windows 7
ERROR:

```
` sudo npm install -g node-gyp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: node-gyp
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/gurbani/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "node-gyp"
npm ERR! cwd /home/gurbani
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: node-gyp
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gurbani/npm-debug.log
npm not ok`
```

Please help in resolving this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `snode-gyp` in your title? Can you install another package?

Comment: Are you able to install other packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sudo apt-get install gcc
then update all packages

Comment: Thanks . Its worked after updating my gcc pakages and installing g++ .